# Crystal Crosstab - access summarized values

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am trying to access the summarized fields in a crosstab in order to determine which is the greatest value in a row.

My data displayed is as follows:

> ```
>                Jan Feb  Mar   Quarter  
> clerk 1 shoes   0    3    1       4    
> clerk 1 pants   5   10    10     25
> ```

What I need to display on the report is that the major item sold by Clerk 1 is pants.
I am table to do this on a monthly basis but not summary level.  Any ideas?

Thanks, Holdfast

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `Embeeded Summary` at grand total level and write maximum or minimum formula to retrive, but one issue here is when you insert embeeded summary then you will get extra row at each level of the cross tab.

```
Note: This is possible in CR 2008 and I have tested in CR 2008
```